# Add products per page filter in WooCommerce Product archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

I have set the main shop page via WooCommerce settings, right? You can choose only one main shop page. Additionally, I have created another simple page using Elementor (both were created using Elementor as well). I inserted a 'Products' element into that simple page. While the pagination works well and the products are shown, the 'Products per page' setting isn't functioning as it does on the main products page. Hooks like `add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'custom_function');` are also being ignored on that simple page. Do I need to code it from scratch? Any help, please? For example, this is working in main shop page, but not in that simple page where is 'products' element included.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Awesome Plugin
Description: This is a fantastic plugin that does amazing things.
Version: 1.0.0
Author: John Doe
Author URI: https://example.com
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) return;

if (!function_exists('tf_display_products_per_page_dropdown_on_shop')) :

    add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'tf_display_products_per_page_dropdown_on_shop', 25);

    function tf_display_products_per_page_dropdown_on_shop()
    {

        $perPage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        $perPagesOptions = array(
            '' => 'Posts Per Page',
            '12' => 'Show 12',
            '24' => 'Show 24',
            '48' => 'Show 48',
            '96' => 'Show 96',
            '192' => 'Show 192',
            '384' => 'Show 384',
            '-1' => 'Show All'
        );

        echo '<div class="woocommerce-perpage">';
        echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';

        foreach ($perPagesOptions as $value => $label) :

            echo "<option " . selected($perPage, $value) . " value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";

        endforeach;

        echo '</select>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

endif;

if (!function_exists('tf_change_products_query_for_page')) :

    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tf_change_products_query_for_page');

    function tf_change_products_query_for_page($query)
    {

        $perPage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('product')) :
            $query->set('posts_per_page', $perPage);
        endif;
    }

endif;
```

Any help much appreciated.

To make woocommerce 'show x products per page' dropdown work on simple page. hooks working only on that page where it is set as main via woo settings.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work on all WooCommerce archive pages, replace your last function hooked in `pre_get_posts`, with:

```php
if ( ! function_exists('filter_products_by_page') ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_products_by_page' );
    function filter_products_by_page( $q ){
        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            $perPage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            
            $q->set('posts_per_page', $perPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Now as I don't use Elementor, I can't tell why `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` hook isn't working. You could try to use a shortcode like:

```php
if ( ! function_exists('add_per_page_filter') ) {
    add_shortcode  ('per_page', 'add_per_page_filter' ); 
    function add_per_page_filter(){
        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        tf_display_products_per_page_dropdown_on_shop();

        return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered content
    }
}
```

Then you will use the shortcode `[per_page]` in Elementor.